# Mock RestTemplate gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, mockito, resttemplate

I have the class and the test class below, when I run my test, the restTemplet is always coming null in this line

```
when(restTemplet.getForEntity(uri, JsonNode.class)).thenReturn(resp);
```

Here is my class

```
   class MyClass {

     @Resource(name = "restTemplate")
     private RestTemplate restTemplate;

     @Resource(name = "uri")
     private String uri;

    public void retrieveData(String id) {
   
      URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
                .buildAndExpand(//**my variables**//).toUri();

      ResponseEntity<JsonNode> resp = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, JsonNode.class);
       
    }

   }
```

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MyClassTest {

  @InjectMocks
    private MyClass mockMyClass;

  @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Mock
    private JsonNode mockJsonNode;

    private static final String URI_GET = "https://myurl";

  @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mockMyClass, "uri", URI_GET);
    }

   @Test
   void test() {
        
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(URI_GET).
                                        buildAndExpand(CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER, "1234").toUri();
        
        ResponseEntity<JsonNode> resp = new ResponseEntity<JsonNode>(mockJsonNode, HttpStatus.OK);
        when(restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, JsonNode.class)).thenReturn(resp);

}
```

Edit: Sorry about the typo, I fixed the typo

Comment: Where is `restTemplet` defined?

Comment: restTemplet is defined in class as restTemplate and correctly mocked but as restTemplate. Somewhere is a restTemplet that is not mocked in your code

Comment: Sorry about the typo while posting the question, i fixed the typo

Comment: You need to create an All Args Constructor of MyClass in order to @InjectMocks works

Comment: MyClass is a @Component class, do i still need to create an All Args Constructor for that?